# Hibernate Envers: Audit Reader throws LazyInitializationException when trying to get revision history

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers, hibernate-entitymanager

I successfully configured Hibernate Envers entities I want to audit, but when I try to get audit history using Audit Reader I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. Code snippets is shown below.

Domain model `Part.java`:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Audited
@Table(name="part")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer"})
public class Part implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer weight;

    public Part(String name, Integer weight){
        this.name = name; this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/part")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class PartController {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    private final PartRepository partRepository;

    @GetMapping("/get-all")
    public List<Part> getAll() {
        return partRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/insert")
    public Part insert(@RequestBody Part part) {
        return partRepository.save(part);
    }

    @PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public Part update(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id, @RequestBody Part part) {
        part.setId(id);
        return partRepository.save(part);
    }

    @GetMapping("/get-history/{id}")
    public List<Part> getHistory(@PathVariable Integer id)
    {
        AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
        List<Number> revs = auditReader.getRevisions(Part.class, id);

        return revs.stream()
                .map(rev -> auditReader.find(Part.class, id, rev))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity deletePart(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id) {
        Part part = partRepository.getById(id);
        partRepository.delete(part);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
}
```

For example, when I add new part, my audit tables *Part_aud* and *Revinfo* are successfully updated, but when I call **/api/part/get-history/1** (assuming 1 is ID of recently added object) I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.io.Serializable org.hibernate.proxy.LazyInitializer.getInternalIdentifier()'
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.EntityInstantiator.replaceNonAuditIdProxies(EntityInstantiator.java:114) ~[hibernate-envers-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.EntityInstantiator.createInstanceFromVersionsEntity(EntityInstantiator.java:69) ~[hibernate-envers-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.EntityInstantiator.addInstancesFromVersionsEntities(EntityInstantiator.java:153) ~[hibernate-envers-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.applyProjections(AbstractAuditQuery.java:341) ~[hibernate-envers-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.EntitiesAtRevisionQuery.list(EntitiesAtRevisionQuery.java:133) ~[hibernate-envers-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractAuditQuery.java:116) ~[hibernate-envers-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.reader.AuditReaderImpl.find(AuditReaderImpl.java:121) ~[hibernate-envers-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.reader.AuditReaderImpl.find(AuditReaderImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-envers-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.reader.AuditReaderImpl.find(AuditReaderImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-envers-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]
    at com.example.demo.controller.PartController.lambda$getHistory$0(PartController.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1621) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.demo.controller.PartController.getHistory(PartController.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.controller.PartController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$efd5d667.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.example.demo.controller.PartController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6b34e12f.getHistory(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The version of hibernate-core and hibernate-envers must match.

Comment: You saved my day. After matching the version of hibernate-core and hibernate-envers the issue was resolved.

Comment: yup, works fine. Thanks

Comment: lifesaver! worked for me